# fetching node values in groups using XPath

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I have an XML of format

```
...
<parent>
   <child name='a' />
</parent>
<parent>
   <child name='b' />
   <child name='c' />
   <child name='d' />
</parent>
...
```

Now, i'm using XPath expression `//parent/child[@name]` to fetch the child node names. But I'm getting everything in a flat list, in this instance its a list of 4 nodes. 
Is there a way (xpath expression) to fetch the nodes grouped by the parent as in `[[a],[b,c,d]]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you need two loops, one on `//parent`, and then a sub query for `child[@anme]`. That should allow you to work with the child names in their groups. XPath will otherwise just return all matching nodes, irrespective of ancestry.

Comment: Yeah, Just figured that out... implemented it... n its working fine. THanks for the quick response.